# Finding maximum value of a function on two variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

[image: 1]]

This was asked in one of our tests.I have no idea what to do.The solution given is as follows.[image]

Well,The thing is..I neither understood this solution nor can think of any other way...It would be really appreciated if an alternate easier solution is provided and this one explained .Thanks

Comment: Which step u did not understand say I will explain it

Comment: I did not understand anything in the first step

Comment: What part of the solution do you not get?

Comment: As $a^2 + b^2$ is always less than or equal to $(a+b)^2$

Comment: How does the inequality change? root goes away

Comment: Is there actually no other way?

Comment: In my above comment apply root on both sides

Comment: I kinda want another way to approach the problem

Comment: Put F(y) = integral then for a turning point, $F'(y) = [y^4+y^2(3-y)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0$ giving y = 0 as the only real solution (clearly a min value $F(0)= 0$). Since there is no local maximum, the max in $F(y)$ must occur at the boundary of the interval i.e $y=3$.